# How can I fix the pink coloring during rendering?

Tags: rendering, texturing

[image]When I was looking around on how to fix the pink coloring, I ran into a problem. Everybody who has this problem is because of imported textures, however I have not imported any textures, I did use the shade editor but I don't think that's the problem. I don't know what to do.

Comment: please share your file at https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 2):

The missing texture might be caused by a missing HDRI in your scene world's, material nodes. You can check this by going to <kbd>Shader Editor - Shader Type: World</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: I didn't use an HDRI either

Comment: Do you still get the pink if you switch to Cycles? Do you get any console errors?

Comment: Yes, not console errors though

Comment: @SimplyChaos The pink is not caused by using an HDRI or not, it's caused by setting up the world material to show an HDRI but then not using any.

Comment: yes exactly. very well said

Answer (score 0):

That is missing HDRI. Either change the setting (in red box) or Open an HDRI file

[image]

or delete the texture node as pointed out by @RPaladin

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the help.